# Trying to develop a simple shortcode

Tags: wordpress, function, shortcode

Basically, I'm trying to do a simple shortcode wherein the user can display a fixed size of an image regardless of the size. For Example [gallery] image [/gallery] it will be displayed like this

http://i255.photobucket.com/albums/hh140/testament1234/thumb_zps5820cef3.png

I tried coming up with my own code but looks like my codes are wrong. I'm not familiar with PHP or WordPress coding yet. I know things like this can be done using plugins but I would rather learn how to code

```
function image_gallery($atts, $content=null) {
   extract(shortcode_atts(array(
     'width' => 400,
     'height' => 200,
   ), $atts));
   return '<div class="gallery"></div>';
}
add_shortcode('gall', 'image_gallery' );
```

the styles was provided via style.css

Answer (score 0):

```
function image_gallery($atts, $content=null) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'width' => 400,
        'height' => 200,
        'image' => ''
    ), $atts));

    return '<div class="gallery"><img src="'.$image.'" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'" /></div>';
}
add_shortcode('gall', 'image_gallery' );
```

activate the plugin

in your post or page add this shortcode [gall image="path_to_your_image"]